# Copy and Paste Cell on Form Submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

On form submission on Google Sheets, I want to be able to copy and paste one specific cell in the new row. I want to do this in the same cell, but as value.  (It's a formula dependent on a variable that changes and I want it to paste as a value once submitted for historical data purposes).

EDIT:  Apologies for being vague.  Javascript is not my forte, and I'm new to google scripts.  I took some code from Nate Sargent in a Quora answer and edited it as follows to do what I was looking for...

```
function pasteValue(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('INVOICES')
var lastRow = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

lastRow.forEach(function (row,index) {
    if (row[1] == "") {  
        lastRow.length = index;
    }
});

var newRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow.length,13);
newRange.copyTo(newRange, {contentsOnly: true})
sheet.setActiveRange(newRange);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that purpose there is a handy shortcut: <kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>+<kbd>`SHIFT`</kbd>+<kbd>`V`</kbd> which does that. simply use a standard copy and paste it with this combo to paste only values without formulas. with script you would need to do something like:

```
function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A1');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet2!B1'), {contentsOnly: true}); }
```

where you move the content of `Sheet1!A1` as a value to `Sheet2!B1`

Comment: Let me rephrase--im looking for a script to automate that process on form submission.

Answer (score 0):

This will paste the value in `A1` of Sheet1 into the next available column on the row where the data for this submission occurred.

```
function copyAndPaste(e) {
  e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnEnd +1).setValue(e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1').getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pasteValue(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('INVOICES')
var lastRow = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

lastRow.forEach(function (row,index) {
    if (row[1] == "") {  
        lastRow.length = index;
    }
});

var newRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow.length,13);
newRange.copyTo(newRange, {contentsOnly: true})
sheet.setActiveRange(newRange);
}
```